# jQuery: Comparing strings in if statement not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that isn't working for some reason. I've narrowed down the issue to the variable itself, but I'm not sure why the variable doesn't work...

```js
var style = $('.user-profiles .custom-field-profileboxstyle td:last-of-type').text();

if (style === 'Sandwich') {
  $('.user-profiles').append("I am a sandwich.");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user-profiles">
  <table>
    <tr class="custom-field-profileboxstyle">
      <td>Profile Box Style:</td>
      <td>Sandwich</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

It seems to work when I set the variable like this:

```
var style = 'Sandwich';
```

However, I need to use the jQuery text selector.

Comment: did you try to console.log the style after first line where you use .text() ?

Comment: _isn't working for some reason_: Works fine for me. Please describe the behaviour of not working.

Comment: I edited your code to running script and everything seems fine No ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your above code works but the main reason your `style` comparison in `if` is not working could be the trailing and leading whitespaces in `td` so you can use `trim()` in `style` so that the whitespaces are removed and compared to string without spaces like below. It is always safe approach to use `trim()` on string comparison so that you get the desired output as expected.

```js
var style = $('.user-profiles .custom-field-profileboxstyle td:last-of-type').text();

if (style.trim() === 'Sandwich') {
  $('.user-profiles').append("I am a sandwich.");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user-profiles">
    <table>
        <tr class="custom-field-profileboxstyle">
            <td>Profile Box Style:</td>
            <td> Sandwich </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, this did solve my problem. I'm using ProBoards and I suppose the original code has whitespace in the td for whatever reason.

Comment: @Caligosus -- Though this did solve your problem, this was a typo in the question. This question is meant to be closed as off-topic or should be deleted altogether. There are hundreds of such posts already on SO, and this doesn't add any value to the future readers.

Comment: @31piy Eh, I suppose, even though I didn't realize the original code had whitespace. I'm just glad to have my issue answered despite googling it for hours before asking myself.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. You are probably trying to execute the script when the elements are not loaded. Try to execute it when the document is ready.
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

```js
var style = $('.user-profiles .custom-field-profileboxstyle td:last-of-type').text();
console.log(style);
if (style === 'Sandwich') {
    $('.user-profiles').append("I am a sandwich.");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user-profiles">
    <table>
        <tr class="custom-field-profileboxstyle">
            <td>Profile Box Style:</td>
            <td>Sandwich</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must append a TD?? because it works but you are not appending a td but you are appending out of the table try this...

```
var style = $('.user-profiles .custom-field-profileboxstyle td:last-of-type').text();
if (style === 'Sandwich') {
    string = 'I am a sandwich.';
    $('.custom-field-profileboxstyle').append("<td>"+string+"</td>");
}
```